# How to Convert ssis Rawfiles to Parquet

Tags: azure, ssis, ssis-2012, azure-data-factory

Currently we are using rawfiles destination in SSIS and i'm wondering is there way to create parquet destination in ssis or converting rawfiles into parquet ? Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Comment: Please share some code of what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry i don't have written code in hand, my question is if at all possible to convert .raw files to parquet.

Comment: Hey Bala, I answered a question similar to this. It depends where the Parquet files will live. See the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60920245/ssis-sending-source-oledb-data-to-s3-buckets-in-parquet-file/60922733#60922733

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Azure Data Factory, you can refer to the following link to learn more about writing to parquet files:

- [Parquet format in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-parquet?view=tfs-2018)

If you are using SSIS, there is no parquet destination component to be able to write data into parquet files or to convert Raw files into parquet, but there are some component that let you write into HDFS files which may helps in some workaounds:

- [Hadoop and HDFS Support in Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/hadoop-and-hdfs-support-in-integration-services-ssis?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Hadoop Connection Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/hadoop-connection-manager?view=sql-server-2017)
- [HDFS File Destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/hdfs-file-destination?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I will give try Hadi. Thanks you